# Creating a closeable tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-bootgrid

In jQuery, I have created a dynamic tab named `closedable-tab`. I want to have a "close" icon showm in this tab, and if I click it, the tab will be closed.

How to implement that?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li role="presentation" class="">
    <a class="tabs-li" href="/online_issues/index">tab1</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a class="tabs-li" href="/online_issues/index">tab2</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a class="tabs-li" href="/online_issues/index">tab3</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a class="tabs-li" href="/online_issues/index">tab4</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active"> 
    <a class="tabs-li closeable-tab-li" href="/online_issues/index">closeable-tab</a>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

Below is an image illustrating the desired result:

[image]

Comment: `close` in the sense remove the tab ?

Comment: @SusheelSingh, Actually, I am ok with both `close` and `remove`. Is there an way to do that? I am new to jQuery.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation follow this

Answer (score 1):

The manipulation tab maybe what you want:
https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation